# How to remove the numbers in the file in java

Tags: java, text-mining

This is my code..Help me remove the numbers before comma and print both the words

```
for(int y=0;y<nso.length;y++)
        {
                File e=new File(nso[y]);
                BufferedReader be=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(e));
            String st,t;
            while((st=be.readLine())!=null)
            {
                if(st.contains("ns"))
                {
                    int offset=st.indexOf("(");
                  st=st.substring(offset+1, st.length()-3);  
                   System.out.println(st);
                  ap.write(st);
                  ap.println("\n");
                }
            }
            ap.close();
            be.close();
```

The file contains

```
 phone-6, This
    know-8, I
    looking-5, you
    phone-14, this-
    graphics-2, has-
```

Comment: Your question needs improving i.e. clarification. Where is this "Comma"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `st.replaceAll(regex,"")` here to replace all numbers with `""`.
For example 

`String result=st.replaceAll("[0-9]+","");
System.out.println(result);`

Answer (score 1):

I can provide you the steps

1. Split the string with ,
2. Then iterate over that array of string and split it with -
   3Then print that array i think that is what you require.

Answer (score 1):

use regexps :

```
st.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
```

this replaces numbers by empty strings.

if you want to get rid of the - :

```
st.replaceAll("[0-9\\-]","");
```

the \ is compuslory. For more details this page is usefull : 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 st.replaceAll("-(\d)*","")
```

\d represents the numbers